# How does copy-on-write give one optimization for fork-exec?

Tags: linux, fork, exec

I really searched through topics on stackoverflow but still cannot get it.

> vfork() is an obsolete optimization. Before good memory management, fork() made a full copy of the parent's memory, so it was pretty expensive. since in many cases a fork() was followed by exec(), which discards the current memory map and creates a new one, it was a needless expense. Nowadays, fork() doesn't copy the memory; it's simply set as "copy on write", so fork()+exec() is just as efficient as vfork()+exec().

When calling `fork()` I get no copy of memory for a child. Okay. But then -- the child calls `exec()` and **overwrites** its code with the code of another binary. So the **write** happens. So it looks like the copy of parent process's memory must happen. So where is the optimization for this `fork()+exec()`? I mean when I call `exec()` the copy does happen, is not it? So COW does **not** help in any way for `fork()+exec()` and does not optimize out anything, am not I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the old pages got overwritten with the new code, then it would indeed be pointless, but that's not what happens. When you call `exec`, all of the old process's COW memory pages get unmapped, and entirely new ones get mapped, so other than the tiny amount of memory written to in between the `fork` and `exec` (basically just the page with the top of the stack), there won't be any copying.